# Highlight disabled day in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

i need to highlight a disabled date from datepicker

what i have now is like this

[image]

the only available day is Tuesday, so i wanted to highlight the disabled day

this is my javascript

```
<script>
    var idf = '';
    var hari = '';
    $('.divradio').hide();
    $(".divradio input").prop('disabled','disabled');
    function getIndex(data, id) {
            var date = $('#' + data).datepicker('getDate');
            var dayOfWeek = date.getDay();
            $('.divradio').hide();
            $(".radio" + idf + hari + " input").prop('checked', false);
            // $(".radio" + idf + hari + " input").attr('disabled','disabled');
            $('.radio' + id + dayOfWeek).show();
            $(".radio" + id + dayOfWeek + " input").removeAttr('disabled');
            idf = id;
            hari = dayOfWeek;
            // console.log(".radio" + idf + hari + " input");
        };
</script>
```

what should i do to achieve that?

Comment: Make [mre] with sample data using snippet by pressing `<>` in editor. You can load date-picker using links from examples source code: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ , Pictures do not help. Short answer: loop  day rows, if all in one column are disabled, target header row and highlight...

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery UI you can use Theming with CSS to do this. Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
      if (dt.getDay() == 2) {
        return [true, ""];
      } else {
        return [false, ""];
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-datepicker-unselectable span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


Date:
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```